# react-native: LayoutAnimation and useNativeDriver: true for flex

Tags: react-native, react-animated, layout-animation

In the past, I have used `LayoutAnimation.scaleXY` to animate the `flex` of a `View` at a very high framerate. Now, I want to use `Animated` to animate `flex` and achieve a similar high framerate.

I know I cannot use `useNativeDriver: true` to animate `flex`.

Does `LayoutAnimation` always run animations natively? If so, how can it run a `flex` animation while `Animated` with `useNativeDriver: true` cannot?

Is there a way around this? I want to run my `flex` animation in parallel with many other animations (e.g. `opacity`, `translate`, and `scale`) and without `useNativeDriver: true` the animation is unacceptably choppy.

P.S. My question addresses `flex` but are there any notable differences for `height` and/or `width`?

Answer (score 4):

According to [this article](https://medium.com/@Jpoliachik/react-native-s-layoutanimation-is-awesome-4a4d317afd3e), "LayoutAnimation works by identifying views by their unique key, computing their expected position, and relying on the underlying native framework (CoreAnimation on iOS) to animate the change.", so apparently `LayoutAnimation` always runs animations natively.

In the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html), there are two animation frameworks, UIKit and Core Animation (might be similar for Android), Core Animation being more powerful than UIKit.

So if I had to guess, `LayoutAnimation` can animate `flex` while `Animated` cannot because `LayoutAnimation` uses Core Animation while `Animated` uses UIKit.

`flex` is different than height/width because `flex` is always a fraction of the parent container (e.g. two `View`s with `flex: 1` wrapped inside a parent `View` will each take up 1/2 the length in the direction of `flexDirection`).